# Quickfixn Fix 4.2 How to Send & Receive messages to different TargetCompID in same session

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

How to send & receive Fix messages to different TargetCompID in same session

```
public void ToAdmin(Message message, SessionID sessionID)
{
if ( (message.ToString().IndexOf("35=D") > 0) || (message.ToString().IndexOf("35=G") > 0) || (message.ToString().IndexOf("35=F") > 0))
{            message.Header.SetField(new TargetCompID("1"));
}
}
```

> 9:56:38 ToApp:
>   8=FIX.4.2�9=261�35=D�34=63�49=555�50=BBBBBB�52=20180918-06:56:38�56=0�128=1�129=AAAAAA�1=555-----126�11=1�21=1�22=4�38=2500�40=2�44=0.03�47=C�48=JO3109211016�54=2�55=JO3109211016�58=Testing
>   Fix
>   Connec�59=1�60=20180918-09:56:38.579�109=126�110=50�111=100�9596=2�9947=55500350�10=140�
>   9:56:38 Exchange:
>   8=FIX.4.2�9=115�35=3�34=73�49=0�50=AAAAAA�52=20180918-09:56:38�56=555�45=63�58=cannot
>   process order: TargetCompID is invalid�372=D�10=067�

Comment: You are better off manipulating the header and trailer portions using the config file, rather than doing it in your code.

Comment: sounds like an odd thing to do in FIX protocol... but you never know what a specific acceptor might want you to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

TargetCompID is a part of Session's identifier, see http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html:

> A FIX session is defined in QuickFix/N as a unique combination of a BeginString (the FIX version number), a SenderCompID (your ID), and a TargetCompID (the ID of your counterparty).

So it seems incorrect to try to send messages to different `TargetCompID` within the same session; you need to create a separate session for each `TargetCompID`.

Simplest is defining sessions in configuration file (see the link above); alternatively you can create them dynamically - see http://lists.quickfixn.com/pipermail/quickfixn-quickfixn.com/2016q1/000277.html